# Recurring Wi-Fi disconnection

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sony VAIO. I also have Windows 10. The Wi-Fi on Windows works great - it has good speed and hardly ever disconnects. On the other hand, it sucks on Ubuntu. I am repeatedly disconnected, it's got slow speed and reconnection is impossible sometimes - I have to "forget" the connection and then rejoin. I have to mention that I've recently did a fresh install of 14.04. Prior to this, I hardly had any problems with Wi-Fi.

Please help.

The Wi-Fi driver is a Centrino-N 100 from Intel on Windows, and I think it's the same on Ubuntu too.